# Do I need to check the pointer before using noalias in Eigen(c++)

Tags: c++, eigen

Assume there are three matrix a,b,c
a and c share the same buffer but with different name

should do some check like

```
if(a.data() == c.data()){
    a = b * c;
}else{
    a.noalias() = b * c;
}
```

Or I could just write a = b + c?

Edit : full example

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

#include <iostream>

using namespace Eigen;

template<typename Derived>
void sigmoid(MatrixBase<Derived> const &input, MatrixBase<Derived> const &weight, 
             MatrixBase<Derived> &output)
{
    output = weight * input;
    output= 1.0 / (1.0 + (-1.0 * output.array()).exp());
}

int main()
{
    MatrixXd weight = MatrixXd::Random(2, 2);
    MatrixXd input = MatrixXd::Random(2, 2);
    MatrixXd activation;
    for(size_t i = 0; i != 2; ++i){
        MatrixBase<MatrixXd> const &Temp = 
                i == 0 ? input : activation;
        sigmoid(Temp , weight, activation);
    }
}
```

The example already simplify, the case is, when i == 0, the Temp should be input, when it is not, it should be activation.

Comment: That really depends on the rest of your code. Are you only doing sums? Can you provide a fuller example? Also, read [this](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html) and [this](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicWritingEfficientProductExpression.html).

Comment: @Avi Ginsburg Sorry, it should be matrix multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your underlying assumption that the data pointers will match is incorrect. Just to prove that, try this:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd aa = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(5,5);
Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> gg(aa.data()+5, 4, 5);
std::cout << aa.data() << "\n";
std::cout << gg.data() << "\n";
```

So, you would have to either know at compile time if they share the same buffer or not (or think of a better test). With the limited example shown, I think you'll have to write `a = b * c` just to make sure `a` and `c` don't overlap.